# What is the best way to store author of change and display changes of every column in temporal table in SQL Server?

Tags: .net, history, sql-server, versioning

I would like to store history of changes in table and also remember author of change. I created temporal table. This table contains `ChangeAuthorId` column which value I update every time when table is updated. I would like to display every changed value separately in one log row with date, old value, new value, author of change and column name.

Below is example database and code which works, but I would like to do it simpler. I think it's not perfect way to do it, because for example I may forget to add author of change. Have you got any ideas to do it better? Maybe there's some convetion or special database functions for that?

I know asking a database for every author of change may be bad idea, but it's just the quick example.

This is my example table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE Person   
( 
    PersonId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1,1), 
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Email varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Country varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ChangeAuthorId int NULL,
    SysStartTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
    SysEndTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime)   
)   
WITH    
(   
    SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.PersonHistory)   
);
```

Person table records:

[image]

And PersonHistory table records:

[image]

This is example code to display changes made on Bart Simpson by anyone:

```
namespace TemporalTablesTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext())
            {
                var bart = context.People.Single(p => p.Name == "Bart Simpson");
                var bartHistory = context.PersonHistory.Where(x => x.PersonId == bart.PersonId).OrderByDescending(x => x.SysStartTime).ToList();

                // First element of history must be actual person values, so it can be easily compared in a loop below
                bartHistory.Insert(0, new PersonHistory
                {
                    Name = bart.Name,
                    Email = bart.Email,
                    Country = bart.Country,
                    ChangeAuthorId = bart.ChangeAuthorId,
                    SysStartTime = bart.SysStartTime,
                    SysEndTime = bart.SysEndTime
                });

                for (int i = 1; i < bartHistory.Count(); i++)
                {
                    Person changeAuthor;
                    if (bart.PersonId == bartHistory[i - 1].ChangeAuthorId)
                        changeAuthor = bart;
                    else
                        changeAuthor = context.People.Find(bartHistory[i - 1].ChangeAuthorId);

                    if (bartHistory[i - 1].Name != bartHistory[i].Name)
                        displayLog(bartHistory[i - 1].SysStartTime, changeAuthor, "Name", bartHistory[i].Name, bartHistory[i - 1].Name);

                    if (bartHistory[i - 1].Email != bartHistory[i].Email)
                        displayLog(bartHistory[i - 1].SysStartTime, changeAuthor, "Email", bartHistory[i].Email, bartHistory[i - 1].Email);

                    if (bartHistory[i - 1].Country != bartHistory[i].Country)
                        displayLog(bartHistory[i - 1].SysStartTime, changeAuthor, "Country", bartHistory[i].Country, bartHistory[i - 1].Country);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void displayLog(DateTime time, Person changeAuthor, string columnName, string oldValue, string newValue)
        {
            string changeAuthorName = changeAuthor != null ? changeAuthor.Name : "deleted user";
            Console.WriteLine($"{time}: User {changeAuthorName} changed {columnName} from {oldValue} to {newValue}");
        }
    }
}
```

And program output:

```
27.11.2016 16:20:31: User Bart Simpson changed Email from bart@example.com to bart.simpson@example.com
27.11.2016 16:16:12: User Homer Simpson changed Country from Scotland to USA
27.11.2016 16:16:04: User Homer Simpson changed Country from USA to Scotland
27.11.2016 16:15:14: User Homer Simpson changed Email from bart.simpson@example.com to bart@example.com
```

Comment: The answer is almost certainly going to be ["Use triggers,"](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/) and/or possibly some form of [Change Tracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx).

Comment: Take look to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/201527/5934037). Change log, decoupling the audit data from the data model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not shadow each field (except you have a strong requirement) but just have a table with `Date`, `PersonId`, `FieldName` and `NewValue`. `OldValue` is superfluous as it can be reconstructed from history.

An example record would be (leaving out `Date`)

```
ID Field   NewValue
2  Email   bart.simpson@example.com
2  Country USA
2  Country Scotland
2  Email   bart@example.com
```

You could generalize that more by having `Table`, `PK`, `Field`and `NewValue` instead.

```
Table  PK Field   NewValue
Person 2  Email   bart.simpson@example.com
Person 2  Country USA
Person 2  Country Scotland
Person 2  Email   bart@example.com
```

Comment: I was doing it similar way before, but I learnt about table versioning in SQL Server 2016 and I wanted to use it in my program. Maybe old idea is better, because with temporal tables I can't do migrations in EF and history tables take much more space.